# Ubuntu 12.10 as Oracle VM Guest. No HDMI?

Tags: radeon, hdmi, oracle, virtualization

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a Windows 8.1 Host using Oracle VM.  The monitor that I run Ubuntu on is plugged into an HDMI port with an HDMI cable, but the display only gives me 2 options: 800 x 600 or 1280 x 720.  I gave it 128mb Video Memory (which was the maximum possible), and 3d Acceleration.  I also installed the Radeon video driver.

Is there a way I can get it to take advantage of the HDMI hardware?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install VB guest additions and enable Auto resize. here is one way to do it:

-Open a terminal

-apply these commands:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-utils

-After installation complete Restart and login to the system.

you can now resize the window and the screen will automatically adjust itself... (if it didnt work.. then make sure that the Auto-Resize Guest Display is enabled by clicking on "Auto-Resize Guest Display" under View tab)

Comment: I already have installed the guest additions and enabled Auto-Resize.  That is what is allowing me the 1280 X 720, before I did that I could only use 800 x 600. :(

Comment: I guess 720p technically is High Definition, I was just hoping it could go to 1080 but I can live with 720 :)